# How to merge several Sentinel-2 images using the median for the overlapping areas?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, sentinel-2, gdal-merge

I'm having a little bit of trouble coming with the best way to do this. I have several rasters that contain each 12 Sentinel-2 bands, not all from the same tile that I want to do some preprocessing and then merge them together.
Some of the images have overlapped pixels, and for those cases I want to calculate the **median** of the pixels.

I've looked at gdal warp and merge but I haven't found a way to do this.

Is there a proper way to do it in python using either rasterio or GDAL?

EDIT:
I found a way to get the **mean**:

```py
        mean_data = []
        for tif in mean_tiles:
            mean_data.append(rio.open_rasterio(tif, mask_and_scale=True))
        
        print("Creating mean raster")
        raster_sum   = merge_arrays(dataarrays=mean_data, method='sum')
        raster_count = merge_arrays(dataarrays=mean_data, method='count')

        raster_avg = raster_sum/raster_count
         
        ouput_mean_image = os.path.join(output_path,f"{name_mosaic}.tif")
        raster_avg.rio.to_raster(ouput_mean_image)
```

But I cannot figure it out how to get the **median**. Also is this a safe way to do this if I have a lot of images?

Comment: You have the individual bands from different tiles and want to merge for example B2 in tile1 with B2 in tile 2 and B2 in tile 3?

Comment: @BERA no. I have a raster that contains all sentinel-2 bands. and i want to merge all these images together for a mosaic. Now, in the cases where there are overlapped pixels between images, for all the bands in the raster I want to get the median value of the pixel.